# How to test the cuda program

Tags: testing, cuda

I have written a cuda program for vector addition and vector multiplication but I don't know how to test the outputs for the program, whether the answer/output is correct or not.Is there any way to test the correctness of the program and aslo is there any online dataset to use for cuda vector/matrix addition/multiplication ?

Answer (score -1):

The generic way is to write the exact same implementation of the kernel and generate the result [gold standard] on CPU, and compare it with the output of GPU kernel. That means copy the output array to the host and compare on CPU. For Vector add/multiply you can generate a random array and generate output on both CPU and GPU (with the same input array) then compare on CPU.

Comment: But how would you know that your "gold standard" is correct? Isn't that just the same question, but now with two problems instead of one?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestoin what if the matrix/vector size is very huge e.g: 1000000000000

Comment: @talonmies Usually we PORT a code in CUDA when we require more performance that means you already have a code in place. In this case, I suggested to implement gold standard as its fairly easy [vector add/ multiply], available online and easy to debug manually as well as programaticaly. However, you are the best person to answer (and I request you to), "How do I ensure accuracy of a code written only in CUDA WITHOUT gold standard" :)